# Update the Text of TextView in a Fragment of a Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have a tabbed activity, in that there are two fragments. There are some TextViews in one fragment. But i cant update the texts of these textviews. I tried many ways. this is the code.

```
    public static class Holder extends Fragment{
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER1 = "section_number";
    public Holder(){

    }
    TextView Name, Age, Medicine, Doctor, CareTaker;

    public static Holder newInstance(int sectionNumber){
        Holder fragment1 = new Holder();
        Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
        args1.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER1,sectionNumber);
        fragment1.setArguments(args1);
        return fragment1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile,container,false);
        TextView Name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fName);
        Name.setText("No Name");
        return rootView;
    }
```

i have already given these TextViews some Pre-Defined values from the XML.

Comment: Use  `onTabSelected` callback ,get the fragment instance then set

Comment: Im new to android, can you please elaborate?